# Prolem with numbers and special characters when uploading files to server in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, base64, url-encoding

The below code is working for me.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url String");

    try {
        String fileStream = "VGVzdApGbIgdGVzdGuZw";
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filenamewithextension", "upload.png"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filestream", fileStream));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
        String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(CREDENTIALS.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/largedata");
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return getStringFromInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

If the stream contains numbers or special characters (String fileStream ="VGVzdApGb3IgdGVzdGluZw==") not working. I have tested different ways to resolve the issue. But I can't get a proper solution.
Can any one please assyst me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ ? Are you getting any exception in your logs?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is the response from server - The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The Messaging Engine failed while executing the inbound map for the message coming from source URL:"url" with the Message Type ":2#UploadDocumentRequest". Details:"Function 'ScriptNS0:UploadDocument()' has failed."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure because you didn't post your log, but I had a similar issue with an App I was working on for iOS. For HTTP, they have encoding rules. You may need to "percent-escape encode" your HTTPPost.

For example:

www.website.com/security/authorizekey?url=www.website.com?user=bob

When the above link was used as my URL Post, the rules of HTTP truncated my Post so that the server only received "www.website.com/security/authorizekey?url=www.website.com?user=" and truncated my user "bob".

According to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), the characters that should be permitted unescaped are the alphanumeric characters, plus "-", ".", "_", and "~":

```
2.3. Unreserved Characters

Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved purpose are called unreserved. These include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

See section 2 of the aforementioned [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for more information.

Anyways, a solution might be similar to the following:

**Potential Solution:**

You may have to encode `String fileStream ="VGVzdApGb3IgdGVzdGluZw=="` with something like:

```
String fileStream = URLEncoder.encode("VGVzdApGb3IgdGVzdGluZw==", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for this replay. I have attempted the same thing, but the response is same from server. ie, Request error - Details:"Function 'ScriptNS0:UploadDocument()' has failed."

Comment: Can you see what the server is receiving? i.e. the URL and headers that the server is receiving from the Post? What is it saying? When I had a similar issue, the server showed that the special characters were causing unintended truncation.

Comment: The exception stack trace is:

at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkAsyncResult.End() 
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkServiceInstance.EndOperation(IAsyncResult result) 
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkServiceInstance.Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.ITwoWayAsync.EndTwoWayMethod(IAsyncResult result) at AsyncInvokeEndEndTwoWayMethod(Object , Object[] , IAsyncResult ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AsyncMethodInvoker.InvokeEnd(Object instance, Object[]& outputs, IAsyncResult result)

Comment: at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeEnd(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage7(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Comment: What is the URL that the server is receiving? What other headers, etc. is it receiving?